# Two Delete statements in a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Given the following :

```
1 = foo
2 = bar
```

How can I write this into a stored procedure:

```
DELETE FROM `2014-04` WHERE `2014-04`.Started LIKE '2014-04-11%' AND `2014-04`.Switch = 'foo';
DELETE FROM `table2` WHERE `name`=1 AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`table2`.merged))='2014-04-11';
```

The first delete statement uses 'foo', where the second delete statement uses the `int` value representing 'foo' (`name=1`).  This option can be either `foo` or `bar`

For the `2014-04` this should be obtained from a Date parameter.

Essentially, I see the procedure itself requiring only two parameters :

```
Date - Y-m-d format
Search - String allowing for either `foo` or `bar`
```

Comment: Let me know if I understand... Lets create a `search` variable. If your `search` var holds the value "foo" then the second statement should contain `name=1`. If `search` holds "bar" then the second statement should contain `name=2` ? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Inside the prepared statement, yes.  But the prepared statement must also do the DELETE commands.  For example, the table name in the first delete is based on the date passed (Y-m), and the LIKE is (Y-m-d).

Comment: How can SP know that `1` is for `foo`, `2` is for `bar`, `3` for ... etc?